# Grep on Linux - How do I replace text with blankspace and newlines

Tags: regex, grep

I'm not use to using grep on linux via the terminal. I'm use to using dnGREP on windows but there is no comparable gui tool on ubuntu from what I've found.

How do I match the regular expressions "**^(.*?)[**" with all files in a folder and replace it with a blankspace?

I assume this one would follow the same methodology "**](?=[^.]*$)**"

Also, how do I replace the text below to add new lines

```
{"dev_is_looking_week"
```

with the same text and 4 blank lines underneath. Ignore the "." at the end. StackOverflow won't show blank newlines without a character at the end.

```
{"dev_is_looking_week"



.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool. `grep` is for selecting data. You may want to use `awk`, `perl` or `sed` instead.

Some examples:

```
awk '/example/ {print; print "\n\n\n\n"; }'
awk '{print;} /example/ {print "\n\n\n\n"; }'
perl -ne 'print $_; /example/ && print "\n\n\n\n"'
```

Note that perl also has the neat `-i` option, for inplace modification of files, which comes in handy when you have to do this change on a lot of files.

Or you might opt for `regexxer`, `redet`, or `kregexpeditor` from KDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed like this:

```
sed 's/{"dev_is_looking_week"/&\n\n\n\n/' file
```

OR using awk:

```
awk '/{"dev_is_looking_week"/{$0=sprintf("%s\n\n\n\n", $0)} 1'
```

Comment: so to process all files in the folder i would do sed 's/{"dev_is_looking_week"/&\n\n\n\n/' *

Comment: For that you run a loop like this: **`for i in *; do sed 's/{"dev_is_looking_week"/&\n\n\n\n/' "$i"; done`**

Comment: What did not work? These type of comment won't help much if you don't provide enough details. Both my answer and the for loop in my previous comment work fine. What behavior are you seeing?